# how can I visualize the lightbox directly magnific popup

Tags: javascript, wordpress, magnific-popup

with wordpress i installed magnific popup, how can I view the popup directly, without the preview of the images? in the work I am doing I need that when I click on an image, the popup opens immediately! I have tried in a thousand ways but I cannot find the most suitable solution

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you’ve written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the delay, I have tried two methods, one is tied directly to the plugin so the code I have to make it work is the following:

```js
(function ($) {

  $('.gallery').each(function() { 
    $(this).magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'image',
        gallery: {
          enabled:true
        }
    });
  });

}(jQuery));
```

it works but as previously said I would like you to be able to view the popup without the preview of the gallery!

the second option i used genesis custom block, the system works but can't find the images here is the code:

```js
(function ($) {

$('a.btn-gallery').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
  
        var gallery = $(this).attr('href');
  
    $(gallery).magnificPopup({
      delegate: 'a',
            type:'image',
            gallery: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }).magnificPopup('open');
    });
  
  }(jQuery));
```

```css
.btn-gallery img{max-width: 100%;height: auto;padding: 30px;}
.hidden{overflow: hidden;display: none;visibility: hidden;}
```

```html
<div class=" block-gallery <?php block_field('className'); ?>">

  <div class="col-100 grid grid--center">

    <div class="col-30">
      <a href="#gallery-1" class="btn-gallery">

        <?php $attachment_id = block_value( 'image-preview-1'); ?>
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'New_quad' );?>

        </a>
    </div>

  </div>

<div id="gallery-1" class="hidden">
    <a href="

  <?php $attachment_id = block_value( 'image-1'); ?>
  <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'New_quad' );?>

  "></a>

  <a href="

  <?php $attachment_id = block_value( 'image-2'); ?>
  <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'New_quad' );?>

  "></a>

  <a href="

  <?php $attachment_id = block_value( 'image-3'); ?>
  <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'New_quad' );?>

  "></a>

  <a href="

  <?php $attachment_id = block_value( 'image-4'); ?>
  <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'New_quad' );?>

  "></a>

  <a href="

  <?php $attachment_id = block_value( 'image-5'); ?>
  <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'New_quad' );?>

  "></a>

  <a href="

  <?php $attachment_id = block_value( 'image-6'); ?>
  <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'New_quad' );?>

  "></a>
</div>


</div>
```

this is the function that calls the block on wordpress:

```html
<?php
use function Genesis\CustomBlocks\add_block;
use function Genesis\CustomBlocks\add_field;

/* gallery */

function register_gallery_block() {
  add_block( 'gallery', array( 'icon' => 'waves' ) );

  add_field( 'gallery', 'image-preview-1', array(
    'control' => 'image'
  ) );


   //gallery-1
  add_field( 'gallery', 'image-1', array(
    'control' => 'image'
  ) );

  add_field( 'gallery', 'image-2', array(
    'control' => 'image'
  ) );

  add_field( 'gallery', 'image-3', array(
    'control' => 'image'
  ) );

  add_field( 'gallery', 'image-4', array(
    'control' => 'image'
  ) );

  add_field( 'gallery', 'image-5', array(
    'control' => 'image'
  ) );

  add_field( 'gallery', 'image-6', array(
    'control' => 'image'
  ) );

  

add_action( 'genesis_custom_blocks_add_blocks', 'register_gallery_block' );
```